# Foreign key relationship betwwen three tables

Tags: sql-server

I have a three tables

1. State : StateID (smallint, primary key, not null), state (char(25), not null)
2. District : DistrictID (smallint, primary key, not null), StateID (smallint, Foreign key with state table, not null), District (char(25), not null)
3. City : CityID (smallint, primary key, not null)

In city table there is some more fileds StateID and DistrictID

My problem is I have to create a foreignkey relation between City table and district table with StateID and DistrictID From both table

Answer (score 0):

You can add a multi-column foreign key like:

```
alter table City 
    add constraint FK_City_District
        foreign key (StateID, DistrictID)
        references District (StateID, DistrictID)
```

A precondition is that there is a unique index on the referenced columns:

```
alter table District
    add constraint UX_District_DistrictID_State_ID
        unique (StateID, DistrictID)
```

Comment: Thank you .. I solved my problem by adding a unique indexes on my district table